# PHP exec works when calling script directly, but not by jQuery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, exec

I have a PHP script which calls `exec()`. I've been having trouble all day with some code calling the same script working and some not (exec() returns a 127 error code).

I have finally worked out that the code that is not working  is the code that is being called from jQuery on my web page:

```
$('#next_button').click(function(event) {
    $.get('download_forms.php', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

However, if I type the url for `download_forms.php` into the address bar of my browser, then exec() will execute properly. I have tries to run other scripts that call exec() from jQuery to test and they all fail, but work if typed into the address bar.

I don't see why this would be an issue. Whether I type the url into Firefox's address bar, or whether pressing the button on my webpage, an HTTP request will be made.

Does anybody know what the difference could possibly be?

Note: I have tried different commands in exec() and they are all failing from my jQuery (note all the rest of the PHP code runs fine) but work when the script address is typed directly into the address bar.

Many thanks

**Update**

This is my download_forms.php code. The initial exec() was just to see if exec() worked at all. As above, it only executes properly if typed directly into the address bar.

```
include ('inc/session.inc.php');
require_once('Downloader.php');
exec('id', $output, $r);
echo var_dump($output);
echo($r);
try {
    $downloader = new Downloader();
    $saveMessages = $downloader->saveToDatabase();
    // exec() in the combineAndDownloadForms() method
    $downloadMessages = $downloader->combineAndDownloadForms();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Further Update**

I made a hyperlink through from my webpage to the download_forms.php page (ie a `<a>`), but exec() still doesn't execute. At least I know it's nothing to do with ajax.

Comment: This is a little bit vague... could you try installing firebug or using some kind of developer tool to see if you are getting any JavaScript errors? What does `download_forms.php` look like?  are you new to ajax altogether?

Comment: @Derek- Thanks for your reply. I've updated my post to include my `download_forms.php` file. I'm not new to ajax, no. Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure the URL in the AJAX is looking in the right place? What is the relative URL of download_forms.php vs. where the file with the js is? Also, if you use Firebug or similar, you should be able to see the request/response of the AJAX call, this might give you more insight into the issue.

Comment: @Jon - thanks for your reply. Yes. I don't know if I made myself clear, but the download_forms.php file is actually being executed. It's just the PHP function exec() isn't running. I use firebug and the only thing being returned in the response is exactly what I would expect (ie just the debugging code that I'm echoing out). The file is running, but the exec() function is only executing if I type the url directly into the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I fixed this issue and all of the above was a red herring.

I hadn't noticed that the page I was on was using the secure `https` protocol, so when the `download_forms.php` script was being used, it was also accessed using `https` and it seems that the `exec()` and `passthru()` functions won't execute commands on the server in these circumstances, which makes sense.

I changed the script so that it changed the protocol of the `download_forms.php` url to ordinary `http` and it's now functioning fine.

HTH